# Hide/Replace Nginx Location Header?

Tags: nginx, security, web-server, http-headers

I am trying to pass a PCI compliance test, and I'm getting a single "high risk vulnerability".

The problem is described as:

Information on the machine which a web server is located is sometimes included in the header of a web page. Under certain circumstances that information may include local information from behind a firewall or proxy server such as the local IP address.

It looks like Nginx is responding with:

```
 Service: https 
 Received: HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
 Cache-Control: no-cache 
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
 Location: http://ip-10-194-73-254/ 
 Server: nginx/1.0.4 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.7 (mod_rails/mod_rack) 
 Status: 302 X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.7 
 X-Runtime: 0 
 Content-Length: 90 
 Connection: Close <html><body>You are being <a href="http://ip-10-194-73-254/">redirect    ed</a>.</body></html>
```

I'm no expert, so please correct me if I'm wrong: but from what I gathered, I think the problem is that the `Location` header is returning `http://ip-10-194-73-254/`, which is a private address, when it should be returning our domain name (which is ravn.com).

So, I'm guessing I need to either hide or replace the `Location` header somehow? I'm a programmer and not a server admin so I have no idea what to do... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, might I add that we're running more than 1 server, so the configuration would need to be transferable to any server with any private address.

Comment: This is a nonsense vulnerability. Location is a HTTP header and HTTP won't work without it. Get the auditor to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: It's an automated test :-/ Will see if I can get to a person to talk to...

Comment: Perhaps they're talking about the Server: or Status: headers in that they disclose the software you're running. That's a nonsense vulnerability, too. Hiding which software you run does not a secure system make.

Comment: I think it's the private address because they specifically said "Description: Web Server Internal IP address or network name available". I emailed the company - hopefully they can do something about it... In the mean time I'll keep trying to figure out how to pass the test...

Answer (score 2):

Well, `302 Found` is an HTTP redirection status, so you were redirected. You were redirected not by `nginx` but by a software behind `nginx` (a Ruby application run on Phusion Passenger as I can see) because there were headers (`X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.7`) added by the backend app not by `nginx`. So, you should check the source code of your Ruby app to find what caused the redirection. The address you were redirected to was not accessible from a public web anyway, so this is not a vulnerability but a kind of misconfiguration.

Comment: Revealing an internal IP address can be considered a vulnerability.